# Free particle propagator - Evaluating Integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, path-integral, integration

In path integral formalism, when evaluating the free particle propagator, we obtain the functional integral of the form,

$$ K_0 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \bigg( \frac{m}{2\pi i\tau}\bigg)^\frac{n}{2} \int \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}dx_i \; \exp\bigg(\frac{im\tau}{2}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(x_{j+1} - x_j)^2\bigg). $$

To begin with, for I have first solve for some finite $n$ case and then generalise by induction. But for even the finite case, I am confused how to do the integral. For instance, with $n=2$ case, I will get an integral of the form,

$$ I = \bigg( \frac{m}{2\pi i\tau}\bigg) \int dx_1e^{\frac{im\tau}{2} \bigg((x_{2} - x_1)^2+(x_{1} - x_0)^2\bigg)}. $$

How am I supposed to solve this integral? I know it just involves some trivial trick of substitution, but am just confused which way to go.

EDIT :

After a bit of evaluation of the integral, I end up with an integral of the form
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{iax^2}\;dx $$ and making a substitution therewith $ s= -iax^2 $ and $ dx = \frac{ds}{\sqrt{-ias} } $, but how do evaluate this kind of integral (i mean what kind of contour can we choose) 
$$ \int_{0}^{i\infty} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{-ias}} e^{-s} $$

PS : A diagram of the contour will be really helpful :)

Comment: Thanks, will refer to it. Although, have I carried out the $n=2$ step properly ? There is only one integral right ?

Comment: Are you sure the $n=2$ case is correct ? Generally when you have this type of integral, you integrate over all $x_i$ variables. In your second equation it seems you still have a $x_2$, $x_0$ dependence.

Comment: @VanillaSpinIce : I don't think so, because, the final answer is such that it contains $x_0$ and $x_n$ :(meaning I don't integrate over them). So I hope this is correct !! Also I just evaluated the integral using Hunter's notes and got it right :)

Comment: The integral over $x_1$ is gaussian, so it's pretty easy to do. If you don't know how to do it, learn that now, because that's the one and only integral you want to learn to do quantum mechanics/field theory.

Answer (score 0):

Note that all your [integrals are Gaussians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#The_integral_of_a_Gaussian_function) in differences of positions at successive instants $(x_k - x_{k-1})$ so implement a change of integration variable from $x_k \longrightarrow (x_k - x_{k-1})$. You will have $N-1$ (straightforward) integrations to perform with $x_0$ and $x_N$ held fixed.

Comment: But as you see, the $n=2$ case has both $(x_2-x_1)$ and $(x_1-x_0)$ terms. Which one am I supposed to substitute for ??

Comment: I don't think this answer is helpful. For starters, to get a feel for what is happening, just expand out each of the quadratic expressions in the exponent and then do the Gaussian integral for $x_1$ ($x_0$ and $x_2$ will be constants).

Comment: Yes, I did that and I think I probably got the right solution !!